# Apps downloaded from Mac App Store won't start due to invalid signature

Tags: high-sierra, mac-appstore, code-signing

I'm currently trying to resurrect my 2010 MacBook Pro 15" while my 2015 is away for repairs. The latest it can run is macOS 10.13.6.

After installing all the latest OS updates and security patches, I'm facing a strange issue: every app that I've installed from the App Store fails to start due to a signing error. Sometimes they also crash on startup, rather than just failing to start.

Uninstalling and reinstalling the apps doesn't help. Apps installed from outside the app store, whether signed or not, work fine. In Security & Privacy system settings, "Allow apps installed from" is set to "Anywhere".

Any idea why this would be happening, and how to fix it?

Sample Console output:

```
default 20:31:42.893857 +0000   kernel  mac_vnode_check_signature: /Applications/Yoink.app/Contents/MacOS/Yoink: code signature validation failed fatally: When validating /Applications/Yoink.app/Contents/MacOS/Yoink:
  Code has restricted entitlements, but the validation of its code signature failed.
Unsatisfied Entitlements:
default 20:31:42.893940 +0000   kernel  proc 6823: load code signature error 4 for file "Yoink"
default 20:31:42.893734 +0000   amfid   /Applications/Yoink.app/Contents/MacOS/Yoink signature not valid: -2147409652
```

Sample Crash Reporter output:

```
Process:               Pages [7034]
Path:                  /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/MacOS/Pages
Identifier:            com.apple.iWork.Pages
Version:               ???
Build Info:            Pages-5249000000000000~2
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Pages [7034]
User ID:               115949

PlugIn Path:             (null)
PlugIn Identifier:       (null)
PlugIn Version:          ??? (551.5)

Date/Time:             2020-11-29 20:37:42.495 +0000
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G14042)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        277B67CC-4E89-F7CC-FA7F-AE59417A41CC

Sleep/Wake UUID:       E63C0512-2451-43AF-8BF3-4227F90C05E0

Time Awake Since Boot: 9800 seconds
Time Since Wake:       480 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x1

kernel messages:

VM Regions Near 0 (cr2):
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000101167000-00000001051ed000 [ 64.5M] r-x/rwx SM=COW  > []

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   ???                             0x0000000110be119c _dyld_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x00007ffeeea98bf0
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x0000000110be119c  rfl: 0x0000000000000200  cr2: 0x0000000000000000
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     0


Binary Images:
       0x101167000 -        0x1051ecff7 +??? (5249) <6DBF698C-C948-37A9-8ADF-CCDB742CD3AB> (null)
       0x110be0000 -        0x110c2aadf +??? (551.5) <CB9BFB56-4511-36F1-A546-891FF770C01C> (null)

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 7743
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=66.6M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=66.6M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=8848K written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=8848K(100%)
 
                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        2 
Stack                             8192K        2 
__DATA                            13.6M        5 
__LINKEDIT                        1808K        4 
__TEXT                            64.8M        3 
shared memory                        8K        3 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            144.2M       13 

Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM 99.0.0.0.0, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.53 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.58f17
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364A53463531323634485A2D3147314431
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364A53463531323634485A2D3147314431
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.102.30)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.7f22, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Crucial_CT512M550SSD1, 512.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Built-in iSight
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Output from codesign requested in comments, for Numbers.app:

```
/Applications/Numbers.app: CSSMERR_TP_CERT_REVOKED
In architecture: x86_64

/Applications/Numbers.app: CSSMERR_TP_CERT_REVOKED
In architecture: x86_64

Executable=/Applications/Numbers.app/Contents/MacOS/Numbers
Identifier=com.apple.iWork.Numbers
Format=app bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=605783 flags=0x200(kill) hashes=18923+5 location=embedded
Signature size=4555
Authority=(unavailable)
Info.plist=not bound
TeamIdentifier=K36BKF7T3D
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=12 files=25878
Internal requirements count=1 size=112
```

Similar for Yoink:

```
/Applications/Yoink.app: CSSMERR_TP_CERT_REVOKED
In architecture: x86_64

/Applications/Yoink.app: CSSMERR_TP_CERT_REVOKED
In architecture: x86_64

Executable=/Applications/Yoink.app/Contents/MacOS/Yoink
Identifier=at.EternalStorms.Yoink
Format=app bundle with Mach-O universal (x86_64 arm64)
CodeDirectory v=20500 size=7586 flags=0x10200(kill,runtime) hashes=228+5 location=embedded
Signature size=4698
Authority=(unavailable)
Info.plist=not bound
TeamIdentifier=G78RJ6NLJU
Runtime Version=11.0.0
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=13 files=249
Internal requirements count=1 size=224
```

Comment: Have added to the original question. CSSMERR_TP_CERT_REVOKED seems to be the key here, I guess...

Comment: Does it happen for apps like Terminal.app in `/Applications/Utilities`? Does it happen for apps like Open Directory.app in `/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/`?

Comment: No, apps installed with the OS are working fine. Only App Store apps are causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work for some things, but not others. E.g. I can now open Numbers and Pages, but Yoink and Tweetbot still fail.

Comment: That works, but I would have to re-buy licences for things that I already bought on the App Store. I’m more interested in figuring out what on earth has gone wrong here.

Comment: Yeah, re-signing is going to break some apps—you're zero-ing out all of the entitlements and letting them run outside a sandbox. Plenty of apps won't mind—you're giving them *fewer* restrictions, not more—but a lot are going to get very confused and do weird things, like crash. The core question is, why were their signatures revoked? (Or why does macOS think they were?) This is really bizarre/interesting, although if you can't tell I don't know what to do...

Comment: `Code has restricted entitlements, but the validation of its code signature failed.` Hm... I do know how to get rid of that problem, although I'm extremely hesitant to actually recommend it... you *could* turn off System Integrity Protection and then run `nvram boot-args="amfi_get_out_of_my_way=1"` and reboot again to turn off AMFI. Without AMFI, apps can use whatever entitlements they want. This is a major change that could break other things, but totally reversible if you wanted to experiment...

Comment: Did you try using those applications on another macOS install? Does it work?

Comment: You can contact the developers to tell them your problems and I think they will be happy to give you a temporary license until the issue is solved.

Comment: Perhaps try launching them in safe mode? Or reinstall the system?

Comment: Sorry for delay in replying, been offline for a bit. Yes, I can use and update the apps on my other Macs with no issues. I've tried safe mode, same problem. I've tried an over-the-top reinstall, which doesn't fix the issue either. Haven't tried the nvram suggestion yet, or a complete nuke and pave.